# How to store and retrieve figures as artifacts in MetaFlow?

Tags: python, plot, serialization, netflix-metaflow

How do I save a plot as a data artifact in MetaFlow? Plotting libraries usually have you write out to a file on disk. How do I view the figure afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to serialize the figure's bytes as an artifact:

```
    from io import BytesIO

    buf = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf)
    self.plot = buf.getvalue()
```

Then, you can fetch the artifact from the run object and directly use the bytes to plot:

```
from IPython.display import Image

Image(data=run.data.plot)
```

Source: https://github.com/outerbounds/dsbook/blob/main/chapter-6/forecast1.py#L21 and @ville on MetaFlow's slack